# How can I pad cells of a blockarray?

Tags: spacing, matrices

After some struggle, I was able to render the matrix I was after. It now has the right "shape", but it does not look very nice; especially the spacing between the bracket and the matrix contents is too small, both horizontally and vertically. How can I solve this? Is there a way to define cell padding?

```
\documentclass{article}  
\usepackage{blkarray}
\usepackage{multirow}
\begin{document}  
\begin{equation}
C =
\begin{blockarray}{cccccccc}
  &   & & & j & & &   \\
\begin{block}{c[ccc|c|ccc]} % [I O]
  & 1 &                                    &     & 0      & 0      & \ldots & 0           \\
  &   & \ddots                             &     & \vdots & \vdots &        & \vdots      \\
  &   &                                    & 1   & 0      & 0      & \ldots & 0           \\ 
\BAhhline{&-------} 
i & \BAmulticolumn{3}{c|}{A_1}             & Q_{11} & \multirow{4}{*}{$B_2+b_2$} &
                                                      \multirow{4}{*}{$\ldots$}  &
                                                      \multirow{4}{*}{$B_n+b_n$}          \\
\BAhhline{&----} 
  & \BAmulticolumn{3}{c|}{A_1+a_1}         & 0      &                                     \\
  &   & \vdots                             &        & \vdots &                            \\
  & \BAmulticolumn{3}{c|}{A_n+A_n} & 0     &                                              \\  
\end{block} 
\end{blockarray}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Hi! :) Could you please edit your code sample so that it becomes a MWE (Minimal Working Example), that is add the necessary code so that other people that want to help can copy the code as it is and be able to compile it? More info about MWE may be found in this discussion: http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that

Comment: @ricmarques Certainly, sorry about that.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The parameter `\BAextraheightafterhline` probably does what you want for vertical spacing. Modifying the horizontal around the delimiters is something of a black art.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}  
\usepackage{blkarray}
\usepackage{multirow}
\begin{document}
  \setlength\BAextraheightafterhline{5pt}
\setlength\tabcolsep{15pt}
\begin{equation}
C =
\begin{blockarray}{cccccccc}
  &   & & & j & & &   \\
\begin{block}{c\Left{}{[\;}ccc|c|ccc<{\;}]} % [I O]
  & 1 &                                    &     & 0      & 0      & \ldots & 0           \\
  &   & \ddots                             &     & \vdots & \vdots &        & \vdots      \\
  &   &                                    & 1   & 0      & 0      & \ldots & 0           \\ 
\BAhhline{&-------} 
i & \BAmulticolumn{3}{c|}{A_1}             & Q_{11} & \multirow{4}{*}{$B_2+b_2$} &
                                                      \multirow{4}{*}{$\ldots$}  &
                                                      \multirow{4}{*}{$B_n+b_n$}          \\
\BAhhline{&----} 
  & \BAmulticolumn{3}{c|}{A_1+a_1}         & 0      &                                     \\
  &   & \vdots                             &        & \vdots &                            \\
  & \BAmulticolumn{3}{c|}{A_n+A_n} & 0     &                                              \\  
\end{block} 
\end{blockarray}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks! Do you by chance know a way to get rid of the tiny line segment to the right of the closing bracket? Or is that an even blacker art? :)

Comment: I noticed that, hoped you wouldn't comment:-) I haven't the faintest idea what blockarray is doing, it was all a long time ago. I may look later (but no promises) (if all else fails you could presumably add a fake last column to force more padding)

Comment: An extra column adds too much padding actually... One hacky approach is to replace `\BAhhline{&-------}` by `\BAhhline{&-------||}` to end up with a point rather than a line segment. Now if I can make that point take the color white somehow... :-P

Answer (score 2):

Here is what you can do with `{bNiceArray}` of `nicematrix` (you need several compilations).

```
\documentclass{article}  
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}  

\[C = 
\begin{bNiceArray}[first-row,first-col,margin]{ccc|c|lcr}
     &   &        &         & j     \\
     & 1 &        &         & 0      & 0      & \Cdots & 0 \\
     &   & \Ddots &         & \Vdots& \Vdots &        & \Vdots \\
     &   &        & 1       & 0     & 0      & \Cdots & 0 \\
  \Hline
  i  & \Block{1-3}{A_1} & & & Q_{11} & \Block[name=one]{4-1}{B_2+b_2} & & \Block[name=two]{4-1}{B_n+b_n} \\
  \cline{1-4}
     & \Block[name=three]{1-3}{A_1+a_1} & & & 0 \\
     &   & &         & \Vdots \\
     & \Block[name=four]{1-3}{A_n+A_n} & & & 0 \\
\CodeAfter 
  \line{one}{two} 
  \line{three}{four}
\end{bNiceArray}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the above code]